# How can I change my c# code to read from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have code like this.

```
td = new Test.Detail();
t = td.Details;          // This is a list of strings
t.Add("aaa");
t.Add("bbb");
t.Add("ccc");
```

It's a source file in VS2010 and it's currently used to load some static data. Now the amount of data has grown so we are considering holding the data in txt files. That way it can be easily modified. I need some way to read this data into the program from my text files that 
look like this:

```
> test1
aaa
bbb
ccc

> test2
ddd
eee
fff
```

The code needs to read in the test1 into a variable, read in and add the following lines to nD
until the blank line. At that point it needs to do some action. Then it needs to start again reading in test2.

Actually there is a lot more to this but I hope someone can give me some advice to get me started on reading data from a file in a loop until some point when I can restart the loop.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried?   Have you searched at all for reading from a file in C#?

Comment: Do you mean that you want one file with all the tests or one file per test?

Answer (score 2):

Serialization.

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class Test
{
    public DetailCollection Details {get;set;}
}
[CollectionDataContract]
public sealed class DetailCollection : Collection<string> {}
```

With these two classes, you can serialize them numerous ways, edit the resulting xml file, and deserialize them at your whim.

there's the classic XML serialization

```
// serialize
var ser= new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
using(var fs= new StreamWriter(@"C:\testdata.xml"))
    ser.Serialize(fs, TestObj);
// deserialize
using(var fs= new FileStream(@"C:\testdata.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    Test test = (Test)ser.Deserialize(fs);
```

which sucks and is buggy.  There is also Xaml serialization:

// serialize
var xaml = XamlServices.Save(test);
// deserialize
var test2 = (Test)XamlServices.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xaml)));

and the DataContractSerializer/NetDataContractSerializer (same pattern for both types, one is .NET centric the other isn't)

```
// serialize
var ser= new NetDataContractSerializer();
using(var fs= new StreamWriter(@"C:\testdata.xml"))
    ser.Serialize(fs, TestObj);
// deserialize
using(var fs= new FileStream(@"C:\testdata.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(fs))
    Test test = (Test)ser.ReadObject(xmlReader);
```

I prefer the latter two, for a number of reasons.  In your case, I would suggest xaml serialization, as if you set the build to **Page**, and use your namespaces (xmlns) correctly (you'll see them defined when you open a serialized file) you'll get intellisense in VS as you edit the files.  Helpful.

<sup>Please note, all code is c#-like pseudocode and may need debugging/syntax editing before they work correctly.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Reading a file is very easy in C#/.NET

```
System.IO.StreamReader file;
using(file = new StreamReader(@"c:\myfile.txt"))
{
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
     // do something with the line
    }
}
```

There are tons of examples of such code if you look for it.

Comment: Gotta wrap this kind of thing in a `using` block, to ensure it's closed properly, like: `using (var file = new StreamReader(fileName)) { /* Do all the file reading stuff */ }`

Comment: @Joe - agreed, and I wondered about that, but thought that someone asking how a file should be read might want a simpler example not layering the good practice of 'using'.  But you're right - so I've edited the answer